# Javascript incorrect output of datetime from rest API

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, timezone, fetch-api

I'm not getting the right time from my datetime field data when trying to fetch the data using fetch API. So here's the data from my database. See image:
[image]

Now, my problem is when I'm trying to print the data using `console.log` it is giving me a wrong time. See image: [image]

Here's the field in my model:

```
date_created =    models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_created=True)
```

Here's my serializer:

```
class Meta:
    model = Message
    fields = [ 'date_created',]
```

Here's also the settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Manila'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I'm not sure where is the problem if it is with the timezone settings? Anyone had an experience of this?

Comment: See this on how to Dates are treated in javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone

Comment: it is the same date.. as you can see the +8 in the DB is applied when you log the JS date (date in JS use the browser timezone)

Comment: @Greedo yah, but look at the hour time. . its not the same. .

Comment: @N.Omugs 13+8 = 21 ;)

Answer (score 2):

The date is same. It is formatted as a string when shown in the console because the API is returning a string.

Try doing this to format the response as a date in `console.log()`

```
console.log(new Date('2020-10-13T13:15:43.384867Z'));
```